# Writing mockable code in C++

Tags: c++, testing, mocking

I am focusing on writing easy to test code these days and I realize that most of my classes follow the skeleton below:

Some class `ObjectManager` needs a `DatabaseRepo`, while there is only one type `DatabaseRepo` in production (`OracleRepo`), I am still implementing it against an interface because I want to be able to mock out the `DatabaseRepo`, thus I need to make use of polymorphism. I inject the `DatabaseRepo` as a `unique_ptr` to the `ObjectManager`'s constructor, in order to indicate that `ObjectManager` owns the `DatabaseRepo`.

One thing, for example, which is flawed here is that in the unit test, I access the state of the `MockRepo` after I moved it into the `ObjectManager`. While its is safe (`ObjectManager`) is still alive it looks like a hack.

---

Question: Using this as a general pattern for the situation where class `A` has an object of type `B`, are there any design aspects I could improve?

---

```
class ObjectManager {
  public:
     ObjectManager(std::unique_ptr<DatabaseRepo> initRepo) : repo(initRepo) {

     }

     void process() {
       repo->updateRecords();
     }


  private:
    std::unique_ptr<DatabaseRepo> repo;
};


class DatabaseRepo {
  public:
    virtual void updateRecords = 0;
} 

class OracleRepo : public DatabaseRepo {
  public:
    void updateRecords() overrides {

    }
}

class MockRepo : public DatabaseRepo {
  public:
    void updateRecords() overrides {

    }
}

testObjectManager() {
   std::unique_ptr<DatabaeRepo> mockrepo = 
       std::unique_ptr<DatabseRepo>(new MockRepo);

   ObjectManager om(std::move(mockrepo)); 
   om.process();

   EXPECT_CALLED_ONCE(mockrepo.get()->updateRecords());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You know that the pointer is going to remain valid until `ObjectManager` is destroyed, but you want to avoid deferencing a moved-from `unique_ptr`. In this case it should be OK to keep the original pointer and use that:

```
testObjectManager() {
   DatabaseRepo* mockrepo = new MockRepo;

   ObjectManager om(std::unique_ptr<DatabaseRepo>(mockrepo)); 
   om.process();

   EXPECT_CALLED_ONCE(mockrepo->updateRecords());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you pass it as an `std::unique_ptr<>` ?

I would use a **non-const reference** instead.

> One thing, for example, which is flawed here is that in the unit test, I access the state of the MockRepo after I moved it into the ObjectManager.

You will be ensured that the mock lives as long as you need it to, as you have full control over the life-time yourself.

Your code will even be simpler, as there is no need to use `new`:

```
testObjectManager() {
   DatabaseRepo mockrepo;

   ObjectManager om(mockrepo);
   om.process();

   EXPECT_CALLED_ONCE(mockrepo.updateRecords());
}
```

Comment: I pass a std::unique_ptr because the ObjectManager manages the DatabaseRepo's lifetime. If I pass a DatabaseRepo reference, then the lifetime of DatabaseRepo can be shorter than that of ObjectManager.

Comment: @user695652 But is there a strict reason why it has to manage the DatabaseRepo's lifetime? Those objects are created once, somewhere in `main()` or another high level; It's not hard to ensure proper lifetime in that case, as using local variables - on the stack - will work correctly.

IMHO, you're creating more problems with this lifetime management of yours than you're solving.

Comment: "But is there a strict reason why it has to manage the DatabaseRepo's lifetime?" Yes because only the ObjectManager knows how long it exists. Note that the ObjectManager can be constructed anywhere, for example in a factory function... There is a notion of ownership semantics and using a unique_ptr is a clear way of indicating that the creator of DatabaseRepo does not need to care about it is lifetime.

Comment: @user695652 The one constructing an ObjectManager knows how long that ObjectManager exists, and can create a DatabaseRepo with at least the same lifetime. Problem solved. (If you really want, you could even create a wrapper struct with two members - the order of constructing and destructing members will take care of the proper lifetime management. But in practice, this is barely ever needed).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to create mocks as `unique_ptr`s, then set up the expectations, then create the class under test (thus invalidating the `unique_ptr`s). So the mocks can be members of the fixture, but the class under test cannot be.

This assumes that the expectations are set up ahead of time rather than checked after the fact. I use gmock, so the assumption holds. Your mocking system may be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can take action in the destructor of `MockRepo` to inform other parts of the test code that the mock has been destroyed.

```
class MockRepo : public DatabaseRepo {
    MockRepo *& signal;
  public:
    MockRepo(MockRepo *& signal) : signal(signal) { signal = this; }
    ~MockRepo() { signal = nullptr; }
    void updateRecords() override {

    }
}

testObjectManager() {
   MockRepo * mock; 

   ObjectManager om(std::make_unique<MockRepo>(mock)); 
   om.process();

   EXPECT_NOT_NULL(mock);
   EXPECT_CALLED_ONCE(mock->updateRecords());
}
```

Note that your program has undefined behaviour, as `DatabaseRepo` lacks a virtual destructor.

```
class DatabaseRepo {
  public:
    DatabaseRepo(const DatabaseRepo &) = delete;
    DatabaseRepo& operator=(const DatabaseRepo &) = delete;
    DatabaseRepo(DatabaseRepo &&) = delete;
    DatabaseRepo& operator=(DatabaseRepo &&) = delete;
    virtual ~DatabaseRepo() = default;
    virtual void updateRecords() = 0;
}
```